# How to save the results of a selection query into several LIST Java ordered by ID?

Tags: java, list

I want to save the results of a query in several Java list grouped by ID.

This is the result of my request:

[image]

I want to have Java list as follows: `List 1 (id = 1, latitude, longitude) / List2 (id = 2, latitude, longitude)` ......

This is my incomplete code:

```
public String  getDistanceTraveled() {

    String f = "" ;
    double distance = 0;
    allDeviceList = (ArrayList<Device>) deviceBean.getListalldevice();// Get list of all device

    List<Eventdata> list = deviceBean.getLatAndLongDeviceId();// Get list of all EventData
    Map<String, List<Eventdata>> map= new HashMap<String, List<Eventdata>>();


        for(Eventdata eventData : list){ 

            if(map.containsKey(eventData.getDevice().getDeviceid())){ 

                    List<Eventdata> tempList = map.get(eventData.getDevice().getDeviceid()); 
                    tempList.add(eventData); 
                    map.put(eventData.getDevice().getDeviceid(), tempList); 
                    //System.out.println("Event data device id: "+"'"+"'"+"'" +eventData.getDevice().getDeviceid()+" ");
            }

            else{ 

                    List<Eventdata> tempList = new ArrayList<Eventdata>(); 
                    tempList.add(eventData); 
                    map.put(eventData.getDevice().getDeviceid(), tempList); 
                    //System.out.println("Event data device id: "+"'"+"'"+"'" +eventData.getDevice().getDeviceid()+" ");        
            } 
        }

        for(String deviceid: map.keySet()){ 

                    List<Eventdata> EventDataListFromMap = map.get(deviceid); 

                    if(EventDataListFromMap.size() > 1){ 

                        for(int i=0; i < EventDataListFromMap.size()-1; i++){ 

                            Eventdata div1=EventDataListFromMap.get(i); 
                            Eventdata div2 = EventDataListFromMap.get(i+1);
                            distance = calculateDistanceByLatLong(div1.getLatitude(), div1.getLongitude(), div2.getLatitude(), div2.getLongitude());


                            //distance = Point2D.distance(div1.getLatitude(), div1.getLongitude(), div2.getLatitude(), div2.getLongitude()); //Save This distance for EventData ID div1.getId() } } }
                            //System.out.println("J'affiche la distance ici"+distance+"'"+ " " +div1.getDevice().getDeviceid()+" " +div2.getDevice().getDeviceid()+"");

                            NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
                            f = formatter.format(distance);


                            System.out.println("J'affiche la distance ici: "+"'"+ " " +f+""+ " " +div1.getDevice().getDeviceid()+" " +div2.getDevice().getDeviceid()+"");

                        }
                    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [MultiValuedMap from Apache Commons Collection](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html) in order to simplify your code:

```
List<Eventdata> list = deviceBean.getLatAndLongDeviceId();
MultiValuedMap<String, Eventdata> map= new ArrayListValuedHashMap<String, Eventdata>();
for(Eventdata eventData : list) { 
    map.put(eventData.getDevice().getDeviceid(), eventData);
}
```

Or better, if your project is Java 8:

```
Map<String, List<Eventdata>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(eventData-> eventData.getDevice().getDeviceid());
```

Comment: Ty for your response but MultiValuedMap and HashMap have the same operation !

Comment: @OthmaneBz yes, it extends Map but it allows to have multiple values for the same key (if you have a look at the `ArrayListValuedHashMap` implementation you should find out that the actual value is an `ArrayList`), and the [get()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiValuedMap.html#get(K)) method returns a `Collection<Eventdata>` that is suitable for your purpose I think.

Comment: What i must import to use this ArrayListValuedHashMap ?

Comment: You can download it from the [Apache Commons Collections dowload page](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/download_collections.cgi) or add the maven dependency `<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
  <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>`